# Why are onclick events inside qtip2 tooltips not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, qtip2

In the jsfiddle link given below, there are 2 buttons and a tooltip is displayed on clicking of any one of them. I want the button inside the tooltip to change the display and other attributes of the "delete" text and "input text"(make the text field editable) The problem is that the value does update but still the text does not become editable" Please suggest a solution to the problem

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9yfw/26/)

### HTML

```
<button id="gear">Gear</button>
<button id="gear1">Gear</button>
<div style="display:none;" id="menu">
    <button class="menuitem">Rename</button><br>
    <input type= "text" id = "try" readonly = "true"><br>
    <div id = "delete" style = "display: block">Delete</div><br>
</div>
```

​

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#gear").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-gear",
            secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    }).qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#menu')
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true,
            modal: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center',
        }
    });
     $("#gear1").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-gear",
            secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    }).qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#menu')
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true,
            modal: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center',
        }
    });
    $(".menuitem").click(function(){
        document.getElementbyId("try").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementbyId("delete").style.display = none;                alert($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

### CSS

```
#gear {
    margin:100px;
}
.menuitem {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: perhaps [this demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#form) can help you

Comment: No this is not what i want..I solved this problem using class for html attributes and accessing elements using classes..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use jquery selectors:

```
$(".menuitem").click(function(){
    $("#try").attr('readonly', false);
    $("#delete").hide();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```